# vscode include error when remotely debugging c++ program

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, plugins

## problem

I'm using `vscode` to remotely connect to `linux` server. When I try to debug on my `cpp` program, which includes these header files under one directory

```cpp
#include "codec_def.h"
#include "codec_app_def.h"
#include "codec_api.h"
```

it always come up with an include error:

```
codec_def.h: No such file or directory
```

the same error shows up to `codec_app_def.h` when I comment out the first header file `codec_def.h`

## I have tried

I googled on this problem and find one solution-include path to the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.
Here is the path screenshot,
[path screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miBpf.png)

and my newly updated `c_cpp_properties.json` file is like this, I added `${workspaceFolder}/codec/api/svc/` to includePath,

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/codec/api/svc/",
                "/usr/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/codec/decoder/core/inc",
                "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7",
                "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/x86_64-redhat-linux",
                "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/backward",
                "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

but I still get the same error and I can't figure out why and how to solve it.

in case of other problems, here are `tasks.json` file

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and `launch.json` file

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        
        {
            "name": "(gdb) run and debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [
                "/root/compress/losslessh264/tibby.264",
                "/fordebug/b.pip"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "set up pretty printing",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "set desassembly flavor Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        },
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug (select script from list of sh files)",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${command:SelectScriptName}",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug (simplest configuration)",
            "program": "${file}"
        }


    ]
}
```

I have been stuck in this problems for days, it will be **a great help** if you know the answer, **thank you** in advance :)

Comment: Note that the include paths added to `c_cpp_properties.json` are *only* for the IntelliSense of Visual Code itself. They are *not* used when building, which only uses `tasks.json` (unless you have Code Runner or similar plugin activated in which case not even `tasks.json` is used). To add custom include directories you need to pass explicit `-I` (upper-case i) options in `tasks.json` to add include paths to search.

Comment: It works! Thank you! But now after all `include` errors, I have come to the `undefined reference` error ;( Exhausted

Comment: Then you're probably not linking with one or more required libraries. Parallell to the "include" directories of this "codec" module or library, is there a *library* directory (usually named `lib`)? Does it contain one or more files beginning with `lib` and ending with either `.so` or `.a`? Those file are the actual libraries. You need to specify the `-L` option to add the path to the libraries (similar to the `-I` option), and then use `-l` (lower-case L) to link with the libraries.

Comment: Note that the library name does *not* include the `lib` prefix or the `.so` or `.a` suffixes. So a file named `libcodec.a` is for the library `codec`. To link with it use `-lcodec`.